# How to control the execution of PHP code

Tags: php

with this example I recap my problem:
The first time I execute this php page I want to echo "I have two buttons".When the user click buttons "next" or "next1" I want to echo "I already said I have two buttons" and not "I have to buttons" again.I proved also with hidden input text but it doesn't work. thk for help

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['already_said'] == false ){
    echo "I have two buttons". date('h:i:s')."<br>";
}

$_SESSION['already_said']=true;

if( isset($_GET["next"]) || isset($_GET["next1"])) {
    echo "I already said I have two buttons". date('h:i:s')."<br>";
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form name="form" method="GET" action="" >  

<button type="submit"  name="next">
<span class="label">Next</span>
</button>

<button type="submit" name="next1">
<span class="label">Next1</span>
</button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you forgot `session_start()`.

Comment: @MarcB - 99 times out of a 100, the say "what" exactly? Ah yes, *"I am using session_start()"*. But fail to put that in there. Well, you stand at being 50% right ;-)

Comment: The Rio games are over (no more golds), but the "green still goes on", which I doubt seeing here.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the important thing is to remember to put the `session_start()` at the top of any script that uses the session. In fact it is a good idea to put it in all your scripts even if a few dont use the session just to keep the session alive.

```
<?php
session_start();

$msg =  "I have two buttons ". date('h:i:s')."<br>";

if (! isset($_SESSION['already_said']) ){
    $_SESSION['already_said'] = true;
}

if( (isset($_GET["next"]) || isset($_GET["next1"]) ) && isset($_SESSION['already_said'])) {
    $msg =  "I already said " . $msg;
}
?>
<html>
<body>
    <div> <?php echo $msg; ?></div>
<form name="form" method="GET" action="" >

<button type="submit"  name="next">
<span class="label">Next</span>
</button>

<button type="submit" name="next1">
<span class="label">Next1</span>
</button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```